# SQL search query (using LIKE) giving priority for column

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using CodeIgniter and active record. I have `posts` table:

```
id | title | body | accepted | deleted
```

Once user is typing a word, `6` posts matching database will be suggested if it is inside `title` or `body` of those posts.

What I want to do is to give priority to those posts who have that phrase inside their `title` over those posts who have that only in their `body`. how to do it?

```
$query = $this->db->select('id,title,body')
->from('posts')
->where(array('accepted'=>'1'))
->where(array('deleted'=>'0'))
->like('title', $seached_text)
->or_like('body', $seached_text)
->limit(6)
->order_by('title','asc');
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it in codeigniter but i know how to do it in sql and maybe this will help you : `SELECT
    id,
    title,
    body
FROM
    posts
WHERE 
    title LIKE '$seached_text'
    OR body LIKE '$seached_text'
ORDER BY
    IF(
        title LIKE '$seached_text',
        CONCAT(1,'$seached_text'),
        CONCAT(2,'$seached_text')
    )` that is why i didn't post it as an answer

Comment: seems `if` and `case` cannot be used as active record.

Comment: the you have 2 choices : 1. do a SQL query 2. order the results after the codeigniter query is executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT id, title, body
  FROM posts
  WHERE title LIKE '%{KEY}%' OR body LIKE '%{KEY}%'
  ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN (title LIKE '%{KEY}%' AND body LIKE '%{KEY}%') THEN 1
    WHEN (title LIKE '%{KEY}%' AND body NOT LIKE '%{KEY}%') THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END, title
LIMIT 0, 6;
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3369c/18/0)**

In this case, rows have the `{KEY}` in both of `title` and `body` come at first, Then the rows have the `{KEY}` just inside thier `title`, and finally those that have the `{KEY}` in `body`.

You can run this query in CodeIgniter by using:

`$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');`

Here is an example:

```
$key = $this->db->escape_like_str($seached_text);

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT id, title, body
  FROM posts
  WHERE accepted = '1'
    AND deleted = '0'
    AND (title LIKE '%$key%' OR body LIKE '%$key%')
  ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN (title LIKE '%$key%' AND body LIKE '%$key%') THEN 1
    WHEN (title LIKE '%$key%' AND body NOT LIKE '%$key%') THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END, title
LIMIT 0, 6;
SQL;

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
```